# Alignment issue in user profile badge section

Tags: support, bug, design, profile-page

There is a alignment issue in user profile badge section.
Numbers for badge are not in one line. [Here's the sample profile link for verification](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164002/surya-sasidhar?tab=profile)
Here's the screen shot for this.

[image]

Comment: What browser are you using?  Do you have a direct to the page that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: I found it in Chrome and FireFox latest versions

Comment: Thanks for adding that link.  I can reproduce it as well; Chrome 47.0.2526.73 beta on Xubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Chiming in that on Safari 9.0.1 (11601.2.7.2) on OS X 10.11.1 (15B42) the badge numbers are in-line (centered vertically).

Comment: Alignment is fine on Safari 9.0.1 on OS X 10.10.5 too.

Comment: There's also an MSE [duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261902/), but it's good you brought it up again. Looks like it completely slips under the radar.